# Stack overflow when adding link dependency. Available stack reduced with linking?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

### Problem

I get a stack overflow if I link against a library, and I don't get it if I don't. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ASSERT_FATAL(cond) \
    do { if (!(cond))  { printf("FAILED COND\n"); exit(-1); }  } while(0)

void *func(void *dummy) {
    // let's make sure the compiler doesn't optimize this out
    volatile char buf[80000];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); ++i)
        buf[i] = rand()  % 128;

    sleep(1);
    printf("Thread finished\n");
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    ASSERT_FATAL(pthread_attr_init(&attr) == 0);
    ASSERT_FATAL(pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 100000) == 0);
    ASSERT_FATAL(pthread_create(&thread_id, &attr, func, NULL) == 0);

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    sleep(2);
    return 0;
}
```

### To reproduce:

- Runs fine with `gcc test.c -pthread -O3`
- Crashes with stack overflow with `gcc test.c -pthread -O3 -Wl,--no-as-needed /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcholmod.so  -Wl,--as-needed`

NOTE: I use `cholmod` because that was the source of my problems in a larger codebase. In Ubuntu you can get it by installing `libsuitesparse-dev`.

### My question

What's going on here? If I increase stack size it will work, but I want to understand what's causing it. Can the .so file do per-thread initialization and somehow reduce available stack space?

**EDIT 1**: changed all C++ code for pure C code

**EDIT 2**: assert result of thread creation/attribute setting

Comment: your code looks like C but you are compiling it as C++, is this on purpose? If you compile it as C++, it is C++ and the C tag can be removed

Comment: @idclev463035818 no it was not on purpose. Same issue happens if I change the code to be C-compatible and use gcc

Comment: The two lines starting with (void) should check the return values as should all the others that have a return value. And your missing a pthread_join at the end. The reason that you get the error is most likely that one of the libs uses some stack themself, but then 80K stack use for a thread might be OK, if its embedded it shouldn't be large, if you don't create many threads on a common PC you can increase it significantly.

Comment: @Surt I simplified the code, avoiding those checks for conciceness.
Can the libraries use stack from threads they don't create? this thread is created by the main app, not a library.

Comment: A stack size of 100000 and a local variable that takes 80000 bytes leaves you with 20k of remaining stack size which is close to nothing nowadays. But I admit that doesn't explain why it works with the first command line and crashes with the second.

Comment: Which line gives the error? do you check every return value in the original code?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, the pthread_attr_setstacksize sets minimum size that will be allocated. (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html)

Comment: @luizinho yes I know. And....?

Comment: I just updated the code so it has asserts to make sure the pthread api calls suceed, which I had already tried but removed from the code for shortness

Comment: I'm confused.  If the program has dependencies on libcholmod, then how can you get a successful link or run without linking that library?  But if it does not, then why are you linking that library at all?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm not sure I get your question completely. In this case I wanted to show that the issue isn't whether I use the lib or not, but that it's enough to link against it. The linker flag --no-as-needed is there to make sure it is kept for linking even though I'm not using any of its symbols. In my original code I'm using the library- it's just this reduced test case that doesn't for simplicity.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the example is representative of a case where `libcholmod` is used.  I suspect that you may be introducing a different problem than in the original code.  In any event, I cannot reproduce your issue on openSUSE Leap 42.3, because there your second compilation command fails hard one a forest of multiple-definition link errors (whereas the first command successfully builds a program that seems to run fine).

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's the same problem as I see the same issue when I run with gdb.
Can you try instead `gcc test.c -pthread -O3 -Wl,--no-as-needed /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcholmod.so -Wl,--as-needed`?

Comment: If I leave out the `--whole-archive` (but keep `--no-as-needed`) then the program compiles, links, *and runs* fine for me.

Comment: @JohnBollinger are you linking against the static version of libcholmod? On ubuntu 18.04 it crashes spectacularly :)

Comment: Obviously not.  libcholmod.so is an ELF shared object, and per the provided compilation commands, I am linking that shared object explicitly.  The commands provided leave no room for a static library to be linked instead.  Indeed, I assumed that was the point of naming the library file explicitly.

Comment: ok then it may only be happening on Ubuntu 18.04 (or similar). Thanks for trying.

Comment: Did you find out what was happening?